# Is there a way to convert categorical variable into dummy with a dict with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently working on a `pandas.DataFrame` whose I need to convert some categorical variables into dummies.

However, as I construct my `pandas.DataFrame` from a proportion of a heavy database, I pretty sure that I'll miss some modalities if I simply use `pd.get_dummies`.

Fortunately, I retrieved all the modalities from the features that I need to convert.

I wanted to know if it's possible (using `pd.get_dummies` or not) ,to efficiently convert my variables depending on the modalities that I retrieved ?

I looked for a solution, with and without get_dummies but didn't found one.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we know exactly what you want/need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`Pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) dtype to handle this.

#### Example

```
# Setup
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], 6), columns=['cat'])
print(df)
```

[out]

```
  cat
0   A
1   B
2   A
3   B
4   B
5   C
```

And running [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) on this yields...

```
pd.get_dummies(df['cat'])
```

[out]

```
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  1  0
4  0  1  0
5  0  0  1
```

---

Now cast this `Series` to `categorical` dtype, and pass in the list of known categories...

```
categories = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
df['cat'] = pd.Categorical(df['cat'], categories=categories)

pd.get_dummies(df['cat'])
```

[out]

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  0  0
3  0  1  0  0  0
4  0  1  0  0  0
5  0  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: I just have to do it in a for loop but perfectly working, thx a lot !